Page refresh stuck on pending indefinitely in sveltekit dev mode
I have a single route that loads up just fine, but whenever I refresh the page or make a change (only to backend files, hot refresh of svelte files works fine) the page gets stuck loading indefinitely. If you look at the network tab of the dev tools it just says (pending) and any additional server calls to API endpoints also get stuck on pending.
This only happens on one specific route, but it is very hard to debug because even with console logs on all of the layout and page server files, I can't find any clue as to why it is stuck in pending.
Another interesting bit of information on this is if I quit the dev server and start it up, the existing pending sessions remain stuck, so even after refreshing the page it still stays frozen. I have to quit the dev server, navigate the browser to a different page (which fails because the server is down), then start the dev server back up.
If I navigate to the page through normal navigation means or even entering in the url directly, everything works fine. It is just when I refresh the page or try to navigate after it already catches that I see this problem.
Anyone else run into this issue or have any hints on how to go about debugging this?

See if the problem exists in another web browser. If it doesn't, then clearing the cache in the first web browser will hopefully resolve the problem.

This happens for multiple users on multiple devices and with different browsers. Definitely seems to be code related. The issue also doesn't exist when switching to a previous branch, but the branch that introduced it integrated auth on every single file, so it's hard to narrow down between branches

I have never had an issue like the one you are describing, so unless you use a newly released version of SvelteKit I haven't tried yet, it is very likely the problem is related to the auth on every single file thing you mentioned. But what is wrong/how to debug it without seeing any code I have no idea about. My best guess is that you await a promise that never gets fulfilled.
